# Modelling the residuals of a model as a function of an external variable in order to assess its effect on the errors of the model?

Tags: regression, error

I am working with field variables and telemetric variables. The dataset is composed of geographical locations for which i have both types of data. Amongst these field data, some are of interest, to be predicted, while some other are just field characteristics.

The initial goal of my study was to model the field variables of interest as a function of telemetric variables.

However, i heavily suspect the field characteristics to affect the prediction performances of my model. I now want to know if the field characteristics have an effect on the errors of the model. I do not wish them to be part of the final model, i just want to know if they have an effect on it.

Therefore i tried to model the residuals of the previous model as a function of the field characteristics and found it to be significant, however the R² being really low.

My question is : Is this methodology relevant for the goal above mentionned ?

**Edit:** I cannot include the field charactristics directly in the models as it is not relevant in the global workflow. The goal being to predict outside of these geographical locations, the field characteristics won't be available to increase prediction accuracy. Hence why i only try to use them to evaluate their importance in the model residuals.

However, if comparing the case when they are included and the case when they are not included in the model is a better option than modeling the residuals based on the field characteristics, then i might try it.

Comment: It might be interesting to look at projective prediction inference with [projpred](https://mc-stan.org/projpred/articles/projpred.html). With this framework, you can develop a "full" reference model incl. the field characteristics. And you investigate whether & how the field characteristics are predictive of the outcome. Then you "project" the reference model onto the subset of predictors that will be available in the global workflow. In this way you'll find the submodel that is "closest" to the reference model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that your approach is somewhat appropriate. It reminds me also of mediation analysis (https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/introduction-to-mediation-analysis), but your example is somewhat different, because none of the variables (neither variables of interest nor field characteristics) can be called a mediating variable. I am just pointing this out, as maybe you will get some insights for that for your analyses. What I believe your problem truly is, is analysis of covariance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_covariance), but in a purely regressive way, i.e., if I understand you correctly, both field data (including variables of interest and field characteristics), and predictions, are on a continuous scale (which is, actually, if I am right, just a plain multiple linear regression model).

> Therefore I tried to model the residuals of the previous model as a function of the field characteristics and found it to be significant, however the R² being really low.

It is one of the symptoms that field characteristics may not have influence on your predictions after all.

What is the result (R²) for model based only on variables of interest?

One more thing that I would do is to create two models:

1. One based on variables of interest, making predictions that you wish to perform.
2. Second, a legitimate model based on field characteristics, making the predictions.

It is save to say that if, e.g., the first model will get R²=0.8  and the second R²=0.2, that the influence of field characteristics is relatively low, and you can discard these variables from your final model.

Another approach is just (for sake of validation), create a third model, with both variables of interest and field characteristics, and then compare its results to the variables-of-interest-model-only.

Disclaimer: the above-described approach is quite utilitarian (practical) one, and if you seek a rigorous statistically and methodologically valid answer to your question you would have to do some further research based on the insights that I provided in my answer. Of the top of my head, and after a quick research I did myself, I do not know what is a fully-proper model, that I would recommend you with clear conscience as a statistically kosher one.

I hope that helps, let me know what your results are, good luck with the analyses.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that great answer :) .  My field characteristics variables are indeed continuous. However, while testing, the effect for some of them was exactly none whilte it was signifcant for an other one. The R squared of 0.02 was part of a model which provided a not so low p-value of 0.02, which is still significant. For the field characteristic which was not relevant, the R² was rather 0.002. Which indicate to me that it is rather a problem of how much it explains the variability of the reisduals.

Comment: And in my case, it is both good news and bad news that it explains only this much (talking of the 0.02 R²). As it should not be the main characteristic determining the residuals.

Comment: If the R² was 0.02 (on a scale 0.0 to 1.0), then I would not care what statistical significance is, because the effect size of such result is, as you said, close to none. In other words, p-value was "significant" (i.e., lower than 0.05) only because of a very low variability, not because of the magnitude of change -- that is general notion valid (I am sure of it) for significance testing for the differences between means. With significance for regression it gets more complex, but the general notion is the same, see: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/2/2.12

Answer (score 6):

You have to be careful with this. Fitting just the residuals is not the same as being included in the model. Here is an R-code example that shows this:

```r
set.seed(1)

### some data
### x and z will be treated as regressors
### y will be treated as response variable
x = rnorm(10)
z = 10*x+rnorm(10)
y = x+0.2*z+rnorm(10)

### model without the variable z included
mod = lm(y ~ x)

### model of the residuals
mod_res = lm(residuals(mod) ~ z)

### model with z included
mod2 = lm(y ~ x + z)


### different significance for the tests of the influence of z
anova(mod, mod2) ### p-value = 0.04007
anova(mod_res)   ### p-value = 0.8017
```

What happened here is that the additional variable $z$ correlated with the variable $x$ that was already in the model. The interplay between the variables due to the correlation is not captured when you just make a single regression of the residuals based on the additional variables.

If you add the old variables in the fitting of the residuals then you do get the correct p-value

```r
mod_res2 = lm(residuals(mod) ~ x + z)
anova(mod_res2) ## now it will be 0.04007 as well
```

And you can notice that the fit of `mod_res2` and `mod_res` are a lot different.

```r
lm(formula = residuals(mod) ~ z)
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.015151   0.269644  -0.056    0.957
z            0.009645   0.037153   0.260    0.802


lm(formula = residuals(mod) ~ x + z)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -0.1738     0.2192  -0.793   0.4539  
x            -5.1987     2.0851  -2.493   0.0414 
z             0.5482     0.2179   2.516   0.0401
```

---

Other ways how fitting residuals might be problematic is when you have non-linear models.

Comment: would you instead advice to just do the mod2 and compare the R², residuals, and p-value with mod ?

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus : That's interesting. I would have expected similar significance  results in both cases.  Why is that residuals(mod) can't be captured by $z$ when $z$ is left out of the original model ? I think that I remember seeing something similar to this in the past in an old thread and didn't understand it then either. Thanks.

Comment: @RenaudBied-charreton I would advise to just keep the field characteristics in the model. Why remove them? If you have some reasons, then formulate those in terms of a cost function that weighs pro's and cons and let that decide. R^2 and p-values are just very rough indicators.

Comment: @mlofton if $z$ contains a part that explains the residuals but also a large part that does not explain the residuals then the fit will be bad. The variable $x$ can correct for the part that does not explain the residuals.

Comment: @mlofton I get the same results with `anova(lm(residuals(mod) ~  x ),lm(residuals(mod) ~  x + z))` which differs from `anova(lm(residuals(mod) ~  1),lm(residuals(mod) ~  z))`

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus i cannot really include them in the model as they won't be used anyway to perform predictions: I work with data which is remote sensed. The field characteristics i'm talkin about cannot be remote sensed, hence why i'm only trying to study their effect on the model, and not really implementing them inside it . I'm trying to study their effect in order to hypothesize that places with those field characteristics are harder to run prediction on. They are mainly continuous variables.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus  The following question is in reference to my original question and not the additional results that you provided in your comment to me. ( Thanks for comment also ).  Is the idea behind it that, since $z = 10x + \epsilon$, x is kind of able to "cover" for $z$ when $z$ is not in the model ? So, regressing the residuals on $z$ doesn't do much.  Thanks.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus So i actually did what you recommended about trying to implement the field characteristics in the model directly. But they don't add any big improvement in the model itsel, they only increase the R² by a few 3%. 
Wheras when modelling the residuals, they would yield 5 to 10% of explaiuned variance...
I don't really know what to do...

Comment: @RenaudBied-charreton how to tackle your situation might not be so easy to say. I am not so sure what your situation actually is. You don't want to use field characteristics but still you want to analyse them. Whether R² changes of 3% are a lot or not, and whether comparison of R² makes sense, that's something that I can't judge. In any case, fitting residuals is not the same as including the variable in the model.